# DBCA and can't init database

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, installation

```
SQL> startup;
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/db_1/dbs/initAWSDB.ora'
```

I created a new Oracle 12c database using dbca

the only files in the dbs directory

```
$ ls -ltrh
total 24K
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall 3.1K May 15  2015 init.ora
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   24 Mar 22 23:10 lkCFRDB
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall 3.5K Mar 22 23:13 orapwCFRDB
-rw-rw----. 1 oracle oinstall 1.6K Mar 22 23:27 hc_CFRDB.dat
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall 3.5K Mar 22 23:27 spfileCFRDB.ora
-rw-rw----. 1 oracle oinstall 1.6K Mar 22 23:42 hc_AWSDB.dat
```

When I tried to start up with init.ora

```
SQL> startup pfile=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/db_1/dbs/init.ora
ORA-01261: Parameter db_recovery_file_dest destination string cannot be translated
ORA-01262: Stat failed on a file destination directory
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Your instance is called `CFRDB`, but you have set `ORACLE_SID` to `AWSDB`.

`export ORACLE_SID=CFRDB`, then try again.

Comment: I did that and I am testing the connection. Someone had me change the host name in the tnsnames.ora and listner.ora file from awsdb to my ec2-......compute.amazonaws.com (I restarted the server). I'll change it back to what it was

Comment: It didn't work. Can you provide additional things to check. I think the issue is that I can't connect remotely

Comment: @softwareisfun No, the issue is that your environment variables are not set properly.

Comment: everytime I setup the env variable, and I restart, it reverts to AWSDB. Any permanent fix?

Comment: I fixed the environmental variable and still same issue